# Verses and Mantras in Veda/ any Hindu Scripture, which speak about Time, Space and Space-time relationship (Spacetime curvature)

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, upanishads, time

Are there **Verses/Mantras in Veda, any Hindu Scripture** which speak about **Time**, speak about **Space**, speak about **Space-time relationship (Space-time curvature)**

(**I dont know what Spacetime Curvature is; I simply used it**)

Comment: Spacetime curvature is a relatively new Physics concept from last century. Dont expect to find it in ancient hindu texts.  In advaita, kAla or Time, is supreme brahman/God, with the power of action as limiting adjunct.

Comment: No need of Spacetime, Vedic Verses with Time, or Verses with Space & Mantra with Time, or Mantra with Space

Comment: Ask only one question per post please. You are asking too many questions in this.

Comment: For Sanskrit Rig vedic verses, you can see here - https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/index.htm

Comment: are there any mantra?

Comment: "of Rig Veda 1-95-7, Rig Veda 1-95-8, R.V 1-115-2, R.V 1-97-7, RV 1-92-2, RV 1-95-1, Maitri Upanishad 4-14-15, RV 1-164-1, R.V 1-131-1, VI-47-8. English Version of Verses is mentioned in the above link." Are you linking to a blog? You already have translation of the mantras but you want Sanskrit mantra. Is this your question? Or have you already found some mantras but looking for more?   Btw, put a @ before user name like @HinduKid so that they can be notified.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Sorry for a lot of edits, I just want Vedic Verses and Mantras which speak about **Time**, speak about **Space**, speak about **Spacetime** relationship

Comment: Mantras which talk  about Shiva being **Time** and Vishnu being **Space**, glorifying its meaning and **Value.** (Shiva is considered as Kala-Time and Vishnu-Space)

Comment: As far as Rig Veda is concerned, Vayu is considered to be Space also, apart from being air.  Some are of the opinion that if one understands Vayu, TIME, SPACE, Energy,etc, can be understood easily.@HinduKid

Answer (score 4):

Time and Space can be better understood through the image of dynamic Goddess Kali(Kala-Time) dancing over Shiva/Shava(static space/Akasha).

[Paramhansa Yogananda, from The Essence of Self-Realization, Ways in Which God Can be Worshiped](https://thecosmicmother.org/home/kali/):

> **Kali represents Mother Nature. She is Aum, the cosmic vibration. In
>   Aum everything exists—all matter, all energy, and the thoughts of all
>   conscious beings.** Hence, Her garland of heads, to show that She is
>   invisibly present in all minds.
>
> The play of life and death expresses Her activity in Nature: creation,
>   preservation, and destruction. Hence the sword, the head, and a third
>   hand extended, bestowing life.
>
> “Her energy is omnipresent; hence Her streaming hair, representing
>   energy.
>
> Shiva, Her husband, represents God in His vibrationless state, beyond
>   creation. Thus, He is depicted as supine.
>
> “Kali is depicted as dancing all over creation. This dance represents
>   the movement of cosmic vibration, in which all things exist. When
>   Kali’s foot touches the breast of the Infinite, however, She puts her
>   tongue out as if to say, ‘Oh, oh, I’ve gone too far!’ For at the touch
>   of the Infinite Spirit, all vibration ceases.
>
> “Those who feel themselves attracted to Nature’s outward
>   manifestations must continue the endless round of life and death,
>   through incarnation after incarnation. Those devotees, however, who
>   deeply long for freedom from the cosmic play worship God in the
>   indwelling Self. Through meditation, they merge in the infinite Aum.
>   And from oneness with Aum they pass beyond creation, to unite their
>   consciousness with God—timeless, eternal Bliss.
>
> **“The Divine Mother is, of course, without form, though we may say also
>   that Her body is the entire universe, with its infinity of suns and
>   moons. She can also appear to the devotee in human form,** however. When
>   She does so, She is enshrined in supernal beauty.
>
> **“All the images of gods in India are symbolic. We must look beyond
>   their shapes to the hidden meanings they represent.”**

The image of Kali-Shiva or or Prana Shakti-Akasha or Time-Space was also explained in the [Gospels of Ramakrishna Paramhansa](https://www.kalimandir.org/sri-ramakrishna-on-the-divine-mother/)

> Whatever you perceive in the universe is the outcome of the union of
>   Purusha and Prakriti. Take the image of Shiva and Kali.
>
> Kali stands on the bosom of Shiva; Shiva lies under Her feet like a
>   corpse; Kali looks at Shiva. All this denotes the union of Purusha and
>   Prakriti.
>
> Purusha is inactive; therefore Shiva lies on the ground like a corpse.
>
> Prakriti performs all Her activities in conjunction with Purusha. Thus
>   She creates, preserves, and destroys.
>
> When I think of the Supreme Being as inactive - neither creating nor
>   preserving nor destroying - I call Him Brahman or Purusha, the
>   Impersonal God. **When I think of Him as active - creating, preserving
>   and destroying - I call Him Sakti or Maya or Prakriti**, the Personal
>   God. But the distinction between them does not mean a difference. The
>   Personal and Impersonal are the same thing, like milk and its
>   whiteness, the diamond and its lustre, the snake and its wriggling
>   motion. It is impossible to conceive of the one without the other. The
>   Divine Mother and Brahman are one.

[What is the difference between Prana and Akasha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35572/16530)

[The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 1/Raja-Yoga/Prana](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Raja-Yoga/Prana)

> By what power is this Akasha manufactured into this universe? By the
>   power of Prana. Just as Akasha is the infinite, omnipresent material
>   of this universe, so is this Prana the infinite, omnipresent
>   manifesting power of this universe. At the beginning and at the end of
>   a cycle everything becomes Akasha, and all the forces that are in the
>   universe resolve back into the Prana; in the next cycle, out of this
>   Prana is evolved everything that we call energy, everything that we
>   call force. It is the Prana that is manifesting as motion; it is the
>   Prana that is manifesting as gravitation, as magnetism. It is the
>   Prana that is manifesting as the actions of the body, as the nerve
>   currents, as thought force. From thought down to the lowest force,
>   everything is but the manifestation of Prana. The sum total of all
>   forces in the universe, mental or physical, when resolved back to
>   their original state, is called Prana. **"When there was neither aught
>   nor naught, when darkness was covering darkness, what existed then?
>   That Akasha existed without motion." The physical motion of the Prana
>   was stopped, but it existed all the same.**
>
> At the end of a cycle the energies now displayed in the universe quiet
>   down and become potential. At the beginning of the next cycle they
>   start up, strike upon the Akasha, and out of the Akasha evolve these
>   various forms, and as the Akasha changes, this Prana changes also into
>   all these manifestations of energy. The knowledge and control of this
>   Prana is really what is meant by Pranayama

The modern scientists behind all the modern discoveries, physics and mathematics also tried to explain the reality in terms of time-space, frequency-vibration etc.,

> We are slowed down sound and light waves, a walking bundle of
>   frequencies tuned into the cosmos. We are souls dressed up in sacred
>   biochemical garments and our bodies are the instruments through which
>   our souls play their music. -[Albert Einstein](https://siobhankukolic.com/secrets-of-the-universe/)
>
> **If you want to find the secrets of the universe, think in terms of
>   energy, frequency and vibration.** 
>    - Nikola Tesla
>
> As a man who has devoted his whole life to the most clear headed
>   science, to the study of matter, I can tell you as a result of my
>   research about atoms this much: There is no matter as such. All matter
>   originates and exists only by virtue of a force which brings the
>   particle of an atom to vibration and holds this most minute solar
>   system of the atom together. We must assume behind this force the
>   existence of a conscious and intelligent mind. This mind is the matrix
>   of all matter.
>
> I regard consciousness as fundamental. **I regard matter as derivative
>   from consciousness.** We cannot get behind consciousness. Everything
>   that we talk about, everything that we regard as existing, postulates
>   consciousness. -[Max Planck](https://bigthink.com/words-of-wisdom/max-planck-i-regard-consciousness-as-fundamental)
>
> After the conversations about Indian philosophy, some of the ideas of
>   Quantum Physics that had seemed so crazy suddenly made much more
>   sense. The Same organizing forces that have shaped nature in all her forms
>   are also responsible for the structure of our minds. - Werner
>   Heisenberg
>
> We do not belong to this material world that science constructs for
>   us. We are not in it; we are outside. We are only spectators. The
>   reason why we believe that we are in it, that we belong to the
>   picture, is that our bodies are in the picture. **Our bodies belong to
>   it. Not only my own body, but those of my friends, also of my dog and
>   cat and horse, and of all the other people and animals. And this is my
>   only means of communicating with them.**
>   Consciousness is a singular of which the plural is unknown. There is
>   only one thing and that which seems to be a plurality is merely a
>   series of different aspects of this one thing, produced by a
>   deception, the Indian maya, as in a gallery of mirrors. - [Erwin
>   Schrodinger](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/1117697)

Answer (score 2):

**Time:** A relative term.  No one can say for sure, as to which point of reference one is talking about in which a particular event occurred, unless we give a particular base.  It can be measured in hours and minutes or muhUrtha or thithi or paksha/fortnight, etc, depending upon the culture/place of reference, etc.

The [Units used in Veda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#Small_units_of_time_used_in_the_Vedas) can be different from that of Used in [subsequent literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time).

**Space:** It is the place from which everything,( ie., matter, water, air, fire), emanated - दयौष (Rig veda).

**“pṛthivyāpastejovāyurākāśāt”** indicates the sequence of initial appearance of the five basic gross elements. Thus, first appeared the space, from which appeared air, from that fire or energy, from which the water, and therefrom the earth.

---

If we view the concepts TIME and SPACE spiritually, then we can understand that the 5 elements - **panchabhUta** - are inside the human being as well as in the outer world.

Emotions/feelings emanate due to attachment to five elements. Finally, everything will merge into that SPACE only.

Spiritually it is called **SELF REALISATION** or merging into **BRAHMAN** and physically it is called **death of a body.**  In order to occur this **SELF REALISATION**/**death of a body**, a particular point of **TIME** is required.

---

In Veda, Indra was mentioned as the BRAHMAN ([Rig Veda 2.1.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02001.htm)), who removes the obstacles while progressing spiritually ([elimination of vritra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vritra#Vedic_version)), finally releases waters (**A BLISS**) to humanity (**INDIVIDUAL**).

Again, it requires passage of certain events and arrival of certain point of TIME, which again being controlled by the Almighty God/BRAHMAN.

Whatever we witness certain events, in between birth and death, will aid in completion of the circle.