# difference in relationship between a human mother and the divine mother

Tags: scripture, manuscripts

I'd really like shlokas from scriptural sources to verify your ideas. And as the question states, what is the difference in relationship **that a son has with his mothers, his human mother and his divine mother.** Just to not get me wrong I know the relationship itself is divine, but I'm just pointing out the divine mother to be maa adishakti, one who is mother of all mothers.

I do have some points already noted, the divine mother is not tied to worldly bonds and hence might be free from any aspiration, expectations with her son, and she is equal and justice to everyone and not just her any *one* son These types of differences are qualitative differences. Another type of difference is a boundary difference which is in how we interact with our mothers and are blessed with their care, love and nurture. There might be other types of differences.

I am not asking what is the difference between the two mothers as one is just a smaller part of the divine, what I am asking is the differences and types of differences that exist in the relationship we have with our two mothers.

Comment: Physical human mother is concrete and for one life, while divine mother aka Shakti is abstract and for eternity known to modern science as Energy. As per modern science, ''Energy can neither be created or destroyed but transformed from one form to another'. Everything is running on energy whether lifeless equipments or your body's immunity and heartbeat. You think you are a body, but its an equipment given to you with you interact with the world for limited time based on predecided individual ambiance called fate, just like gamers enjoy a game but dont want to know the complex game programming

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37384/20089 Read Devi Purana where Shakti is glorified as Goddess.

Comment: @ManuKumar, I read the first sentence but it is pointed towards the difference between mothers, I mean the difference in relationship and the nature of relationship

Comment: If you expect abstract singular formless Shakti to raise infinite jivas parallely, how can be that done in most efficient way? Through limited biological mother, Shakti is the class outside the Maya program while biological mothers are an object of it which inherits some traits of it but only towards their children, not every one.Shakti is spiritual mother,other is material body's mother,but for a normal person unseen Shakti dont exist nor soul, hence Shakti maps to physical mother.One whose mother is suffering from serious disease,yet he is going to faraway Devi pilgrimage,leaving her is fool