# What is the relationship between Rig Veda and Sama Veda?

Tags: vedas, identification-request

What is the proper meaning of the following phase? How do they relate to each other in the following manner?

> If the Rig Veda is the word, Sama Veda is the song or the meaning. If Rig Veda is the knowledge, Sama Veda is its realization. If Rig Veda is the wife, the Sama Veda is her husband.

Comment: Where did you get this quote from?

Comment: I was reading a online post shall I give the link? @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: Yeah, give the link.

Comment: Do you want any other explanation ?

Comment: Please scroll brown to "The Sama Veda: The Book of Song" from the link https://www.thoughtco.com/what-are-vedas-1769572 @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: Nice question, similar question I remember of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10822/277),

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relation between Rik and Saman is described in [**Chandogya Upanishad**](https://archive.org/stream/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English#page/n21/mode/2up)  -Adhyaya 1 - verse 2.

> एषां  भूताना पृथिवि रस: पृथिव्या आपो रस: |
>  अपामोषधयो रस औषधीनां
>   पुरुषो रस: पुरुषस्य वासग्रो
>   वाच ऋग्रस ऋच :साम  रस: साम्न
>   उद्गित्थो रस: ||2||
>
> The earth is essence of all the beings ; Water is the essence of the
>   earth ;Herbs are essence of water ; Man is essence of herbs ;Speech is
>   essence of man ; Rik is essence of speech ; **Saman is the essence of
>   Rik** ; Udgita is essence of Saman .

**In simple words Sama is  Rasa  or essence of Rig-Veda i.e. That is most essential part.**

---

Explanation- Basically this mantra is meant for givings us the idea of  Importance Sama-Veda and above all significance of letter "Om" "ॐ".This is explained by giving the examples.

**Adi Shankaracharya** in his commentary on the above Verse is explaining  this mantra as thus.

> Prithivi (earth) is the "Ashrya" i.e. residing place of rest of the
>   Bhutas i.e. elements.(Agni ,Vayu ,Jal etc.).
>
> The "Aap" jal or water is essence of this earth. Because earth is full
>   of water. (Also water is the support of life on earth ).The essence of
>   water is "Aushadhi's" or "Food" , (because from the water itself food
>   and medicine's are grown) ,which keeps us alive and healthy. The
>   essence of these "Aushadhi's" or "food" is human body. Because our
>   body sustains on food and gets rejuvenated by food and medicine.
>
> The important part or essence of this human body is "Vaak" i.e.
>   speech.(good speech). Because the good speech is "result of healthy
>   body and mind.  The most important or residual part of  all of the
>   speech is Rik (i.e.Rig-Veda) mantras. And the Saman or Sam-Veda is
>   even more refined part of Rik. i.e. Sama is essence (most important
>   part) of Rik mantras. And the ultimate essence of Sama is "Udgita"
>   i.e. Om (for Sam-Vedis).

We can read [**Chandogya Upanishad hindi**](https://idoc.pub/documents/upanishad-bhashya-of-shankar-on-chandogya-upanishad-vol-iii-gita-press-gorakhpurpart2pdf-x4e68xy3mgn3)  with Shankar's commentary here.

---

We can also listen  to a very good explanation of this Verse given by  [**Acharya Satyajit Arya**](https://youtu.be/DdKHGcYbaPo?t=5m42s) .(You Tube)

Seek 5.42

Comment: Good link is provided, I may learn many things from that. But it took so much time load may be my slow network. Yes I would like to know about all  the 3 relations, how each relations satisfy.

Comment: Ok , I will explain this relations in answer , will update the answer tomorrow. BTW do you know hindi? I will provide a good video link  explaining all in answer. :-)

Comment: @KailashChandraPolai And yes this could be because of slower connection. I will add the screenshot as well as hindi commentary in answer tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I do as i stay in Mumbai

Comment: @KailashChandraPolai - Please see the updated answer. And also go through You Tube video lecture on this verse. That will be helpful in understanding the concept and meaning of this verse.

Comment: Perfect answer! Indeed that Chhandogya verse nicely explains it.

Answer (score 0):

In his *Introduction* to his book *The Upanishads: A New Translation*, Swami Nikhilananda writes (p 3):

> Vyasa compiled the Rig-Veda by collection the riks. Of the samans he composed the Sama-Veda, while the Yajur-Veda he composed of yajus. The Rig-Veda, which may be called a book of chants, is set to certain fixed melodies. The Sama-Veda has no independent value; for it consists mostly of stanzas from the Rig-Veda. The arrangement of its verses is solely with reference to their place and use in the Soma-sacrifice. The Yajur-Veda contains, in addition to verses taken from the Rig-Veda, many original prose formulas which may be called sacrificial prayers.

So the Sama Veda is Rig Veda and was arranged for ease of use by priests in the Soma sacrifice.

Answer (score -1):

Rig Veda and Sama Veda are married. The relationship seems to be literal. It is referenced a bunch of times in the Upanishads, such as [this Khandogya Upanishad mention](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01022.htm).

> 5. The Rik indeed is speech, Sâman is breath, the udgîtha is the syllable Om. Now speech and breath, or **Rik and Sâman, form one couple**.
> 6. And **that couple is joined together in the syllable Om**. **When two people come together, they fulfil each other's desire**.

Also, the [Aitareya Brahmana](https://archive.org/stream/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft_djvu.txt) clarifies their relationship as polygamous.

> First there existed the Rik and the Saman (separate from one an-
> other) ; sd was the Rik, and the name amai?i.was the Saman. Sd, which was
> Rik, said to the Saman, '* Let us copulate for begetting children." The
> Saman answered, " No ; for my greatness exceeds (yours •." (Thereupon)
> the Rik became two ; both spoke (to the Saman to the same effect); but
> [ 197 j it did not comply with their request. The Rik became three
> (divided into three) ; all three spoke (to the Saman to the same effect).
> Thus the Saman joined the three Riehas. Thence the Sama singers use
> for their chant three Richas,^^ (that is) they perform their work of chanting
>
> with three Richas, (This is so also in worldly affairs.) **For one man
> has manj^ wives (represented by the Richas), but one wife has not many
> husbands at the same time. From sd and avialt, having joined, sama was
> produced.** Thence it is called sdman.^ He who has such a knowledge
> becomes sdman, i.e., equal, equitous. He who exists and attains to the
> highest rank, is a sdman, whilst they use the word asdmanya, i.e.,
> inequitous, partial, as a term of reproach.